# Best way to get common "likes" from public info page out of your friends list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get a list of common likes (public) between a user and his friends.  I thought this FQL query would work but I'm getting an unknown user error:

--get page_id that you have and any of your friends have

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=
select uid, page_id from page_fan where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) and page_id in (select page_id from page_fan where uid= me())
&access_token=ABC
```

I'm getting this error:

```
<error_response><error_code>1</error_code><error_msg>An unknown error occurred</error_msg></error_response>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the result set is way to big for the API to handle. Your best bet is to try to limit the result set by either query a set of friends against the user's like or query one, two ...etc pages at a time (if that also didn't work try to `LIMIT` your friends to say 100 to make sure you are actually getting something). [Example](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql?q=select%20uid,%20page_id%20from%20page_fan%20where%20uid%20in%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20=%20me%28%29%29%20and%20page_id%20in%20%28select%20page_id%20from%20page_fan%20where%20uid=%20me%28%29%20LIMIT%201%29) of a query:

```
select uid, page_id 
from page_fan 
where uid in (
    SELECT uid2 
    FROM friend 
    WHERE uid1 = me()
) and page_id in (
    select page_id 
    from page_fan 
    where uid= me() 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Obviously there is no `offset` in FQL. So first, you need to retrieve the user's likes and then query against them. You can always use the [batch api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/batch/) to make multiple calls in a single batch call.

Comment: thank you you are absolutely right, the result set must be too large.  i've been able to get results via setting a limit on the "select uid2 from friend" query.  i'm going to try the multiquery fql as well to see if that is a better option

Comment: Looks like even though there's no offset in FQL, you can still filter in the where clause ie "and uid > 248012123 LIMIT 50" and just looping through that way using a new uid

Comment: Well, since Facebook supports `ORDER BY` operator that might actually work!

Comment: please suggest me , this query is displaying empty json object : 
SELECT page_id from page_fan WHERE uid = me() 
and 
page_id IN ( SELECT page_id from page_fan WHERE uid = 100000000464783 )

Answer (score 0):

SELECT page_id from page_fan WHERE uid = me() and page_id IN ( SELECT page_id from page_fan WHERE uid = give one hid here )