# Best way to find common likes between two users

Tags: php, mysql

I have an app that saves user likes from their fb account and then shows common likes when one user visits another one's profile. There are two ways to do that:
1.  Since I already have gotten user1's likes from the database, I can save the IDs in a
string like

```
            $user1_likes="1,2,5,6,10,15,19";
```

and then use this query to find common likes:

```
          SELECT name FROM user_like WHERE uid='user2' AND id IN ($user1)
```

or, I can do this query

```
        SELECT name FROM user_like WHERE uid='user2' AND id IN (SELECT id FROM user_like WHERE uid='user1')
```

The problem with the first method is, if user1 has a lot of likes (say 4000), the query might become too big for mysql to handle. 
The problem with method2 is that mysql should select again what it has already selected.

What do you recommend to handle this situation?

Comment: The "best" way might be to handle this cross-referencing entirely via Facebook. Perhaps [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906366/how-to-get-mutual-facebook-likes-between-users-who-are-using-an-app) might be of interest to you. Or maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215177/best-way-to-get-common-likes-from-public-info-page-out-of-your-friends-list).

Comment: Why not use something like `SELECT a.name FROM user_like as a, user_like as b WHERE a.uid = 'user1' AND b.uid = 'user2' AND a.name = b.name;`? Subqueries nearly always perform bad, while mysql can greatly increase the performance on joins.

Comment: Thank you Sauurai8. I believe this is right join. Can you please tell me how this is superior to left join? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max_allowed_packet has a default of 16 MB (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html), so your first query with 4'000 likes should be no problem at all. Even 10'000 or 100'000 are no problem.

Try to find out which one is faster if there are 10'000/100'000 likes. If you have proper indizes, the second query shouldn't be a problem either.

Personally, I would choose the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Try with JOINS

```
SELECT t1.name FROM table_name AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_name AS t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
WHERE t1.userid = 'user1' AND t2.userid = 'user2';
```